# how can i create a custom validate method to show errors in django forms

Tags: django

I want to made a method that validates some fields like these

```
    def validar_empresa(self):
        ruc = self.cleaned_data['ruc']
        if EmpresaCanchas.objects.filter(ruc=ruc).first():
            raise forms.ValidationError("La empresa ya esta registrada.")
        if self.cleaned_data['nombre_negocio'] == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError('Es necesario el nombre de tu negocio')
        if self.cleaned_data['direccion'] == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError('Es necesario la direccion de tu negocio')
        if self.cleaned_data['telefono_negocio'] == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError('Es necesario un telefono de tu negocio')
        if self.cleaned_data['representante'] == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError('Es necesario el nombre del representante de tu negocio')
        if self.cleaned_data['hora_apertura'] == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError('Es necesario la hora de apertura de tu negocio')
        if self.cleaned_data['hora_cierre'] == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError('Es necesario la hora de cierre de tu negocio')
        return True
```

The code its works but doesn display the errors in the template, just redirect to default error page [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjyqL.png)

My form:

```
class ResgitroUsuarioForm(ModelForm):
    dni = CharField(max_length=8, widget=TextInput(attrs={'type':'number'}))
    nombres = CharField(max_length=256)
    apellidos = CharField(max_length=256)
    telefono = IntegerField()
    password1 = CharField(label='Password', widget=PasswordInput)
    password2 = CharField(label='Password confirmation',
                                widget=PasswordInput)
    tengo_negocio = BooleanField(required=False, label="Tengo un Negocio")
    nombre_negocio = CharField(max_length=129, required=False)
    ruc = CharField(max_length=11, required=False)
    direccion = CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    telefono_negocio = CharField(max_length=9, required=False)
    representante = CharField(max_length=128, required=False)
    hora_apertura = IntegerField(max_value=23, min_value=0, required=False)
    hora_cierre = IntegerField(max_value=23, min_value=0, required=False)
```

My template:

```
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Where are you calling validar_Empresa()?

Comment: is a Modelform and it is call in save() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a `clean` method inside your ModelForm and call `is_valid` before saving and check it's return value if it is True (valid) or False (invalid), please check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#using-forms-to-validate-data).

```
class ResgitroUsuarioForm(ModelForm):
    ...

    def validar_empresa(self):
        ...

    def clean(self):
        self.validar_empresa()
```

Comment: thanks, i could even implement my logic inside the clean () method, right?

Comment: Sure you could, but encapsulating your logic allows you to make a more readable code, however you're the one to decide it ;D Happy coding!